# Web Part Error: Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource

Tags: web-part, permissions

I created four site pages for one list; each page has its own view as not everyone can see all the columns within the list. 
I then assigned unique permissions to each page and stopped the inheritance from the parent. 
However, the user is getting the following error:

> Web Part Error: Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource. Correlation ID: 175a449e-d06e-5000-ca38-6f63b8afd2a9.

Any assistance would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wrong approach for managing views for different audiences. Adding a list as a web part to your site page requires that the users who should see the page should also have the permission for the list. When you broke the inheritance from the parent, you also removed the permission to the list which should be displayed in the site page. So, the permission to the source list must remain as that's what you are supposed to display on the site pages.

Additionally you should understand that even if you'd have the permission assigned for the list, directing users to site pages suitable for their user group is ineffective. Users could still navigate to the list with quite basic SharePoint knowledge and see all of the views which would by default show on other site pages. This is just a disclaimer so that you understand the design.